# MvvmCross MvxTabbedPage documentation?

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross, tabbedpage

I'm trying to find documentation on the MvvmCross MvxTabbedPage. I can't find it in the MvvmCross documentation or GitHub repo - hopefully I'm just not looking in the right place!

Specifically, where (if possible) I can adjust the layout of the tab items - e.g. the font style and icon size used in the tabs.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Probably you might want to join the Mvvmslack. Somebody might be able to help you there. Here's the link with the instructions: https://www.mvvmcross.com/support/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MvxTabbedPage](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross.Forms/Views/MvxTabbedPage.cs) is a simple wrapper around Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage adding MvvmCross data binding and MvvmCross ViewModel lifecycle support. MvxTabbedPage doesn't do anything special regarding the font style, icon size, etc. The [Xamarin.Forms TabbedPage documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page) explains how to customize the tab icon.